# Estimating factorial moments from a sample

Tags: beta-function

I saw this article on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution and there is even a small example for the math-dummies like me.
However, there is something I am not getting which is how to estimate the second factorial moment. I've been fiddling with this a bit, but no matter what I try, I never get to 42.31.
If someone could provide a line of code or a formula that computes this, that would be super helpful.
For the ones that like python, here is the data:

```
import numpy as np
n = 12
x = np.array([3,24,104,286,670,1033,1343,1112,829,478,181,45,7])
c = np.array(range(n+1))
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, took me a while, but it is simply that:

```
m1 = sum(x*c)/sum(x) 
m2 = sum(x*c**2)/sum(x)
```

My confusion was that we are not looking for factorial moments here.

Comment: Please clarify your answer and also your question, please.